# How do I extract a single character from a line and put it in a const char*

Tags: c++

I have a text file which I'm going through line by line and taking relevant information from.

However, one of these lines I cannot seem to take the appropriate information from. I'm trying to take a single char from this line and put it into a const char*

The line is like this:

```
                "character" "B"
```

And I'm trying to extract the 'B' character from inside the quotation marks.

```
            std::string Output;

            int Quotations = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < LineText.size(); ++i)
            {
                if ('"' == LineText[i])
                {
                    Quotations += 1;

                    if (3 == Quotations)
                    {
                        Output += LineText[i + 1];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return Output.c_str();
```

I'm grabbing the line just fine and also counting the quotation marks correctly but for some reason the outputted result is:

```
/=�UL��'F/�$/U�
```

Rather than:

```
B
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You return a pointer to local data. The `Output` string goes out of scope as soon as the function returns, and the pointer is then invalid.

Why don't you return a `std::string` instead?

Comment: Or, return a `char` and put it into a `const char*` on the receiving end:)